# Geohash clustring on Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geohash

Leaflet has a markerclustring plugin that clusters markers.

I am asking is there a solution to cluster your (lat/lon) with Geohash on Leaflet map in the a similar way to that on Kibana?

Comment: how does kibana do it?

Comment: like [this](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/tq17IwtqXXFMbGtAP1nejyxSOP_cdUJhYDHjkmpjfTQq560qdHtAykQxjaMDDr4Flvc8gwe3dJMSIAER1r-Jo3Grnf4Wze_FxFUFrepm97hPaXXYKiJnVA1WJz1V5sqOkq3IcXA)